# AIR file is damaged after publish

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I tried to find an answer here but haven't seen anything yet.

I've been working on an AIR application with Flash CS4 (AS3) for the last two days. Yesterday when publishing I was able to install the application (or overwrite existing version) without a problem. Now whenever I publish a new AIR file, it constantly tells me it cannot be installed because the "AIR file is damaged".

There are no actionscript errors or compiler errors when publishing, and I've generated a new certificate at least 3 times already thinking that may expire daily?

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Has the publisher ID of your application changed?

This may be related to you changing your certificate, or any of the details in your certificate.

You can also get this problem if you don't timestamp the app.

My bet though is that your publisher ID has changed, you will be able to set this manually in the imminent release of AIR 1.5.3

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on an AIR application with Flash CS4 (AS3) for the last two days. Yesterday when publishing I was able to install the application (or overwrite existing version) without a problem. Now whenever I publish a new AIR file, it constantly tells me it cannot be installed because the "AIR file is damaged".

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem. Its been driving me crazy. I'll let you know if I figure anything out. I'm reinstalling AIR now.

I don't think it has to do with your FLA file, because I've worked around this issue by moving my .FLA to a different computer (running OS X instead of XP) with Flash and it published fine. This is quite a hack work around, hope it might help.

Answer (score 0):

It must be either problem of including Time Stamp, or don't writing application configuration file correctly.